More computational capabilities per spreadsheet
I am a pro user of Google Sheets and Google Apps Script. Is there any possibility to get more computing capability per spreadsheet? Some of my spreadsheets become unusable due to a large amount of data, complex formulas, or many users accessing the spreadsheet. Linking with a Cloud Console project doesn't resolve the problem. I suppose after linked with GCP it offers the same computing capability.

Exact copy of More computational capabilities per spreadsheet. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

Some tasks are done by client-side JavaScript, meaning the spreadsheet uses the device's resources to open and edit it. In this case, using a computer with more resources and better performance might help.
Other tasks involve API functions like the IMPORT functions, GOOGLEFINANCE, etc. are run on Google servers and there is no way to increase the resources assigned to them.
Regarding Google Apps Scripts, the quotas might vary depending on the type of account and, occasionally, if the user is participating in a special program, like early previews. Replacing the Google Cloud default project with a standard project doesn't increase quotas for standard services like the Sheets or Drive service. However, it adds capabilities like accessing APIs that are not available otherwise, among other things. Some might require a billing account even to use the free tier.
One option is to learn about spreadsheet optimization and software engineering topics like code smell.
A practice that causes code smells in spreadsheets is repeating the same formula, e.g., using fill down, fill right, or copy-paste. The smell (symptom of a possible problem) is proportional to the number of cells having the same formula. In some cases, the smell might eliminated or reduced by using arrays / ranges instead of scalar values / single cells, i.e., on VLOOKUP together with ARRAYFORMULA.
Tips (very few):

Whenever possible, avoid having formulas using volatile functions like NOW, TODAY, RAND, RANDBETWEEN.
Whenever possible, avoid having volatile formulas using functions like MATCH, INDEX, QUERY
Whenever possible, once a calculation is done, replace the formula with the result, i.e., using copy-paste special as value only.
Whenever possible, avoid having formulas returning values for the whole columns and whole rows. ARRAY_CONSTRAIN might be helpful.

References

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quotas

Related

Where does the calculation take place?
Can't open version history of my public Google Sheet


I too would advice against using legacy patterns like index(match()), but these functions aren't volatile, and neither is query(). The latter often offers the best performance among lookup functions so I would say it is counter-productive to avoid it. The today() function isn't volatile the same way now() is, and does not get re-evaluated when the spreadsheet is edited, which is the hallmark of volatiles. Filling a whole column with an array formula is sometimes faster than copying down separate formulas, depending on the nature of source data.
